# what is the efficient way to parse a template like this in php?

Tags: php, templates, string-parsing

**HTML template**

```
<b><!--{NAME}--></b>
...
..
..
<b><!--{ADDRESS}--></b>
```

**PHP Array**

```
array('name'=>'my full name', ..... , 'address'=>'some address ');
```

I have lots of template files and have to parse each of them and replace it the str_replace given data in associative arrays.

I need your suggestions to improve this process or any other technique/tool that might be helpful

**Edit: Current version of code**

static function ParseTemplate($data,$template){

```
    $html=$read==true ?  self::GetCached($template,true) : $template ;

    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        if(is_array($value) ){
            foreach($data[$key] as $aval)
            $html = str_replace("<!--{".$key."}-->",$aval,$html);
        }
        else $html = str_replace("<!--{".$key."}-->",$value,$html);
    }

    return $html;
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a template engine such as [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/#demo), here for the [PHP version](http://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php#readme)

Answer (score 1):

if the array keys are always the same as the template word inside the braces, do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $html = str_replace("<!--{$key}-->", $value, $html)
}
```

if performance is important, it may be better to use strpos on the html, and go over the placeholders one by one. it will be quicker that doing str_replace many times on a large string. but if performance is not an issue, it's not necessary.

EDIT:

```
$index = strpos($html, "<!--");
while ( $index !== false ) {
  // get the position of the end of the placeholder
  $closing_index = strpos($html, "}-->", $index);

  // extract the placeholder, which is the key in the array
  $key = substr ($html, $index + 5, $closing_index);

  // slice the html. the substr up to the placeholder + the value in the array
  // + the substr after
  $html = substr ($html, 0, $index) . $array[$key] .
          substr ($html, $closing_index + 4);

  $index = strpos($html, "<!--", $index + 1);
}
```

NOTE: this wasn't tested, so there may be some inaccuracies with the indexes... it's just to give you a general idea.

I think this is more efficient then str_replace, but you know what? this can use some benchmarking...

Comment: any example about strpos() thing ?

Comment: @sakhunzai added the strpos example

Comment: thanks for you efforts , but it seems Mustaches seems better options as it has some caching support

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think the following should work fine unless I'm missing something.

```
$a = array('name'=>'my full name','address'=>'some address');
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
{
    $html = str_replace('<!--{'.strtoupper($k).'}-->',$v,$html);
}
```